# Salesforce REST API with PHP, INVALID_SESSION_ID after successful authentication

Tags: rest-api, php, curl

I connected my web app to salesforce and successfully followed all the steps in the web server OAuth flow to get an access_token and related info:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_placeorder.meta/api_placeorder/intro_understanding_web_server_oauth_flow.htm

Every step seems to return the expected set of results specified in the docs, but when I try to make requests with the final access token, I get an error saying my session ID is invalid. Here is my code:

```
    // Execute a request for access_token and related info
    $output = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // Display output and curl info
    var_dump($info);
    var_dump($output);

    // Extract token and instance_url from output
    $sf_url = $output->instance_url . '/services/data/v35.0/';
    $sf_auth = 'Bearer ' . $output->access_token;

    // Execute a new cURL request with auth values
    $ci = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_URL, $sf_url);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => $sf_auth,
        'X-PrettyPrint' => 1
    ));

    $output2 = curl_exec($ci);
    $info2 = curl_getinfo($ci);
    curl_close($ci);

    // Display output and curl info
    var_dump($info2);
    var_dump($output2);
```

The dump from $output gives:

```
object(stdClass)#194 (7) { 
["access_token"]=> string(112) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
["signature"]=> string(44) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
["scope"]=> string(3) "api" 
["instance_url"]=> string(27) "https://cs10.salesforce.com" 
["id"]=> string(68) "https://test.salesforce.com/id/xxxxx/xxxxx"
["token_type"]=> string(6) "Bearer" 
["issued_at"]=> string(13) "1453358xxxxxx" }
```

The dump from $output2 gives:

```
string(75) "[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]"
```

Any help here would be much appreciated.

*** UPDATE ***

I also tried using the username-password auth flow, and I'm getting the same result. I can get an access token, but I can't query the database, and the error being returned is the same INVALID_SESSION_ID.

I used the Postman plugin for chrome, passed in all the same info for the username-password flow, and it works for making queries. I'm not sure what is being done differently, seems like all the data being passed is the same.

*** Update 2 ***

The dumps from curl_getinfo() show that the headers aren't being set in the second curl request, but I can't see why.

The var_dump from $info gives:

```
array(27) { 
["url"]=> string(294) "https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?client_id=xxxxxxx&client_secret=xxxxxxxx&username=xxxxxxxx&password=xxxxxxxx&grant_type=password" 
["content_type"]=> string(30) "application/json;charset=UTF-8" 
["http_code"]=> int(200) 
["header_size"]=> int(669) 
["request_size"]=> int(396) 
["filetime"]=> int(-1) 
["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) 
["redirect_count"]=> int(0) 
["total_time"]=> float(0.602597) 
["namelookup_time"]=> float(0.028403) 
["connect_time"]=> float(0.097796) 
["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0.241315) 
["size_upload"]=> float(0) 
["size_download"]=> float(361) 
["speed_download"]=> float(599) 
["speed_upload"]=> float(0) 
["download_content_length"]=> float(-1) 
["upload_content_length"]=> float(-1) 
["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0.601087) 
["redirect_time"]=> float(0) 
["redirect_url"]=> string(0) "" 
["primary_ip"]=> string(14) "xx.xx.xx.xx" 
["certinfo"]=> array(0) { } 
["primary_port"]=> int(443) 
["local_ip"]=> string(11) "xx.xx.xx.xx" 
["local_port"]=> int(45269) 
["request_header"]=> string(396) "POST /services/oauth2/token?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxx&client_secret=xxxxxxxxx&username=xxxxxx&password=xxxxxx&grant_type=password HTTP/1.1 Host: test.salesforce.com Accept: */* Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded Expect: 100-continue " }
```

The dump from $info2 gives:

```
array(27) { 
["url"]=> string(47) "https://cs10.salesforce.com/services/data/v35.0" 
["content_type"]=> string(30) "application/json;charset=UTF-8" 
["http_code"]=> int(401) 
["header_size"]=> int(319) 
["request_size"]=> int(77) 
["filetime"]=> int(-1) 
["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) 
["redirect_count"]=> int(0) 
["total_time"]=> float(0.278246) 
["namelookup_time"]=> float(0.060541) 
["connect_time"]=> float(0.095554) 
["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0.170015) 
["size_upload"]=> float(0) 
["size_download"]=> float(75) 
["speed_download"]=> float(269) 
["speed_upload"]=> float(0) 
["download_content_length"]=> float(-1) 
["upload_content_length"]=> float(0) 
["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0.20641) 
["redirect_time"]=> float(0) 
["redirect_url"]=> string(0) "" 
["primary_ip"]=> string(12) "xx.xx.xx.xx" 
["certinfo"]=> array(0) { } 
["primary_port"]=> int(443) 
["local_ip"]=> string(11) "xx.xx.xx.xx" 
["local_port"]=> int(50733) 
["request_header"]=> string(77) "GET /services/data/v35.0 HTTP/1.1 Host: cs10.salesforce.com Accept: */* " }
```

Comment: If you use the `access_token` and `instance_url` that you get in PHP with the Chrome Postman plugin does the REST API call succeed? If so, there is something with the PHP to cURL interaction.

Comment: Also, try changing your Accept header to "application/json", or omitting it entirely.

Comment: I copied the php access_token and instance_url into postman and it worked. Changing the Accept header in the php code didn't work, nor did leaving it out entirely.

Comment: OK, but we've narrowed the problem down to how PHP is using cURL.  Can you see the raw interaction between cURL and PHP somehow?

Comment: I took a curl_getinfo() from the second exec, and found out that the headers aren't being set. So it looks like that may have something to do with it, but I can't figure out why they aren't being set. It is largely the same code from the previous curl, which works fine. I'll update the post with the dump from curl_getinfo().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer, I had the wrong syntax for setting the curl headers. I tried to pass the values as an associative array, but the correct way is like this:

```
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Authorization:' . $sf_auth,
    'X-PrettyPrint:1'
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it might be a typo.

Try changing:

```
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
    'Authorization' => $token,
    'X-PrettyPrint' => 1
));
```

to

```
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
    'Authorization' => $sf_auth,
    'X-PrettyPrint' => 1
));
```

I.e. there is no variable `$token`. It should be `$sf_auth` instead.

Comment: gah! I was _just_ in the middle of typing this. I hope it's the solution. I'll live vicariously through your answer.

Comment: @MarkPond PHP certainly isn't something I'm familiar with, but it does look like a mismatch. So PHP doesn't bork in any way when an unassigned variable is used?

Comment: I have no idea, I've never actually used PHP. It was just the first thing that stuck out as a source of a bug. :-)

Comment: Sorry about that, the typo is because I pasted code from 2 spots on my test page into this post (fixed now). The actual code that is returning INVALID_SESSION_ID doesn't have this typo. And yes, PHP does throw an error if you try to use an un-initialized variable.

The main problem I'm trying to solve now is understanding why the headers aren't being set in the last curl request.